# How to disable and change color of Yaxis label in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using MPAndroidChart in my project. I set dataset like:

```
 LineDataSet set1 = new LineDataSet(yVals,null);
```

I wrote "null" to label because I don't want show any label to users. When label is null, graph is bigger but the cube that belongs to label still appears.

[image: Here is what I'm seeing.]

So how can I disable the cube?

And also I couldn't change color of label. It is always black. How can I change color of label?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to disable the legend. To do this just access the legend of your LineChart and disable the legend.

```
mLineChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
```

This should erase the square.

[Also you can check out more on the Legend's documentation here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Legend).